# how to make the flex in box flutter to be centered each rows if the one text row long?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I have [boxes list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRyyC.png) and they are not really tiny or not in the centered right, especially the name of the food, because they are too long and make more space on it,

here is my code for the box list

```
class CategoryMeals extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String image;

  CategoryMeals({this.title, this.image});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
      ),
      elevation: 14,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(14),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              fit: FlexFit.tight,
              flex: 2,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                      flex: 1,
                      fit: FlexFit.tight,
                      child: Text(title)
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                      flex: 1,
                      fit: FlexFit.tight,
                      child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text("Button 1"),
                            Text("Button button 2")
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                  )
                ],
              )
            ),
            Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                child: Image.asset(image)
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

here is my expected :

[the result box I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1obvO.png)

do I miss something? or should I use Stack or what else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
class CategoryMeals extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black,width: 1),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(child: Text("askNilesh is here to help you",textAlign: TextAlign.center,)),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[Text("Button 1",textAlign: TextAlign.center), Text("Button 2",textAlign: TextAlign.center)],
            ),
          ),
          FlutterLogo(
            size: 20,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: would this not affect with different width and height ? well the result u answer is what I want, but between button and left text almost close with me if I make button text long, should we use padding ? or margin ?

Comment: @WeqIou use margin

Comment: where I should put margin?